# knife-solo to start configuring chef-solo not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-11.04, chef-infra

[Knife solo](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo) is a knife plugin by mat, and there is a good screencast i saw [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G6bd4b91RU)
After installing ruby, gem and other dependencies i did:

```
sudo gem install knife-solo

Successfully installed knife-solo-0.0.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for knife-solo-0.0.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for knife-solo-0.0.8...
```

and then i get the following:

```
sudo knife configure -r . --defaults
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1450:in `complete': invalid option: --defaults (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in `complete'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1261:in `parse_in_order'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `parse_in_order'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in `order!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in `permute!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in `parse!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mixlib/cli.rb:162:in `parse_options'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/knife.rb:91:in `find_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/application/knife.rb:115:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/knife:24
```

I ignored the above and tried:

```
 knife kitchen mychefrepo
[Sat, 05 May 2012 02:55:21 +0530] FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: kitchen mychefrepo
Sub-Command: client bulk delete REGEX (options)

Sub-Command: client create CLIENT (options)
    -a, --admin                      Create the client as an admin
    -f, --file FILE                  Write the key to a file
..... and the list contnues to show all other options.
```

I am on ubuntu 11.04.
Please let me know whats wrong, thanks.

Comment: What version of chef do you have installed?  (knife -v)

Comment: `knife -v
[Sat, 05 May 2012 13:14:07 +0230] FATAL: Sorry, you need to pass a sub-command first!
Chef: 0.8.16`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knife plugins were added in Chef 0.10.  Upgrade with `sudo gem install chef`.  0.8 is way out of date.

Comment: i tried `sudo gem install chef` and rechecked `knife -v` to get the same version. also the knife solo thing isnt working.

Comment: you must have the old canonical package installed.  do `sudo apt-get purge chef` and then try the gem install again.

Comment: thanks, for help, i used rvm to install ruby 1.9 everything worked fine.

Comment: That works, because the RVM stuff comes first in your path, but you should still remove the ancient chef stuff with apt-get purge just to avoid any future confusion.